# Different public keys after generation pem file from jks file

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption, jks

I have Keystore.jks file and I want to generate public key from it. I have to give the public key file to the other clients who are using my service.

So I generate `foo.pem` file including public key and private key from `Keystore.jks`. I run commands from this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656559/1156041)

After the `foo.pem` file generation, I compare two public key and private key with the original `keystore.jks` file by following coding.

```
    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(
                    "testing"
                    , "123456".toCharArray ()
                );

    Certificate l_cert = keystore.getCertificate ("testing");
    PublicKey publicKey = l_cert.getPublicKey();
    System.out.println("Private Key: "+Base64.encodeBase64String(privateKey.getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("Pub key: " + Base64.encodeBase64String(publicKey.getEncoded()));
```

I would like to know

- Why two public and private keys are different after generation of
  `foo.pem` file?
- What should I do to get same public and private keys
  for both files?

Comment: Why? What you should be giving them is the *certificate*, by exporting it from the KeyStore.

Comment: The only reason is I want to give public key file to clients. So I googling about exporting public key file from keystore jks. I found this answer. I don't know it is suitable or not.

Comment: I asked you *why*? You haven't answered. Restating that you want to do it isn't 'why', or a reason. This is not standard practice.

Comment: Where is the second key? I only see one key in your code.

Comment: I found that answer to extract public key from pem file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271197/openssl-how-to-extract-public-key Thank u for ur time.