# gPRC behind goproxy returns certificate error, works fine without proxy

Tags: docker, ssl, go, proxy, grpc

I have a gRPC client and server, both secured with an ssl certificate. Without a proxy inbetween these work great. As a test, when I purposely create faulty certificates it fails. Proving later in this post it's not a certificate issue.

gRPC server code:

```
// Creates a new gRPC server
// Create the TLS credentials
creds, err := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile("configs/cert/servercert.pem", "configs/cert/serverkey.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not load TLS keys: %s", err)
}
// Create an array of gRPC options with the credentials
opts := []grpc.ServerOption{grpc.Creds(creds)}
// create a gRPC server object
s := grpc.NewServer(opts...)
```

gRPC client code:

```
// Create the client TLS credentials
creds, err := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile("configs/cert/servercert.pem", "")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not load tls cert: %s", err)
}

conn, err := grpc.Dial(grpcUri, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to connect: %v", err)
}
```

now I am trying to use a forward proxy (which ive tested and works fine on normal HTTP api requests). However it constantly fails on gRPC requests through the proxy.

I am using [cuttle](https://github.com/mrkschan/cuttle) which internally uses [goproxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy) with the following setup. Do note that the `InsecureSkipVerify` boolean has been tried both `true` and `false`. With my (limited) understanding of SSL that this needs to be `false` as it will check online for the certificate, and these are self-signed so naturally it would fail. However, again, i tried both `true` and `false`

```
// Config proxy.
proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
proxy.Tr = &http.Transport{
    // Config TLS cert verification.
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: !cfg.TLSVerify},
    Proxy:           http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
}
```

Running a proxy between the gRPC client and server results in the following error:

> transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed
>   by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: invalid signature:
>   parent certificate cannot sign this kind of certificate" while trying
>   to verify candidate authority certificate "test server"

Which would indicate it's a certificate issue, however, gRPC works flawless without the proxy, as stated and tested earlier.

also note: I dont want to run gRPC behind a proxy but am forced to due to development environment. The gRPC server and proxy run on the same docker machine. Having the same IP address would result in the following configuration which would just cancel each other out (trust me i tried anyway).

```
ENV http_proxy 192.168.99.100:3128
ENV https_proxy 192.168.99.100:3128
ENV no_proxy 192.168.99.100 # <- this would be the gRPC server IP, which is the same as the proxy. resulting in nothing being run through a proxy.
```

Splitting the ip addressed in docker would solve this issue, however, I would learn nothing and would like to solve this. I tried configs like answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457953/how-to-specifiy-a-static-ip-address-with-docker-compose-yml-version-3?rq=1) to set different docker internal IP's however, the ip would remain empty (only the network would be set) and accessing on the new IP would just timeout.

Comment: Think about this objectively: if one could place a server in between a client and server TLS connection - relaying traffic in both directions - this would be the very definition of a man-in-middle. A TLS handshake cannot work through a proxy without knowing each party's private keys. And at that point end-to-end encryption is not guaranteed.

Comment: Now that you say it out loud, that makes a lot of sense. I am, however, not skilled enough to understand now how to solve this. The proxy server also has the private key already so shouldn't it at least work, without guaranteed encryption?

Comment: I have run a reverse-proxy https server. Your client needs to use the trust cert, not of the the _server_, but of the _proxy_ in the middle. And the proxy when relaying  to the server needs to have the trust cert of the server.

Comment: @colminator havent heard of trust certificates before. Do i generate those too using openssl?

Comment: I created my own CA certificate and re-created the certs  against the CA. However, now I get the error `Transport: authentication handshake failed: context deadline exceeded`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Background:***

Each end of a TLS connection needs a pre-arranged trust. Most clients use the system trust chain when connecting to a remote host (GeoTrust, DigiCert CA's trusted certs are all listed there and allow you to safely get to sites like https://facebook.com, https://google.com etc.)

`go`, when using TLS, will default to the system-trust-chain when contacting servers. When developing custom solutions, chances are your application server's public cert is *not* in this system-trust-chain. So you have two options:

- Disable trust via `InsecureSkipVerify: true` ([DON'T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47169975/1218512) do this!)
- add a custom trust to your client

Most likely you application server has a self-signed certificate, so it's [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10271238/1218512) to get the public cert portion of this.
You can also see a server's public certs using tools like [openssl](https://superuser.com/a/176721/417258) - using the linked solution you can grab public certs for not only your own development servers but any other remote service - just provide the hostname and port.

---

So just to summarize your situation. You have:

```
Client <- TLS -> Server
```

But want:

```
Client <-TLS-> Proxy <-TLS-> Server
```

So your client now, instead of trusting the Server now needs to just trust the proxy instead - as it is only ever talking directly to the proxy.
The proxy will most likely have a self-signed cert (see above on how to extract the trust cert).
Once you have this, update your `go` code to use this custom trust-file like so:

```
// Get the SystemCertPool, continue with an empty pool on error
rootCAs, err := x509.SystemCertPool() // <- probably not needed, if we're only ever talking to this single proxy
if err != nil || rootCAs == nil {
    rootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()
}

// Read in the custom trust file
certs, err := ioutil.ReadFile(localTrustFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to append %q to RootCAs: %v", localTrustFile, err)
}

// Append our cert to the system pool
if ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs); !ok {
    log.Fatalf("failed to append custom cert")
}

tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    RootCAs: rootCAs,
}
```

The proxy also will need to trust the server - so if the server's cert is not in the system-trust-chain, then it will need a similar tls.Config setup like above.

Comment: Its starting to make a lot more sense to me. However I just cant figure out which certificates go where, it has all become a maze to me. Ill keep trying and mark this as answer later. Sounds and looks like the good answer, i just cant figure it out

Comment: This classic [puzzle](https://goodriddlesnow.com/riddles/view/605) helped me finally understand a TLS-handshake. Public & private key terms are confusing. Within the context of the puzzle: if you think of a public-key as being the Lock; and the private key unlocks it; the concept becomes clearer.  If your client already has the server's Lock (public cert) - when it sends it a message - only that server can unlock it (as it has the private key for that lock).

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, and others reading this. The code above solves my issues exactly as described, I was just as dumb as an egg to provide the wrong certificates (aka provide server key when CA was required). Thanks a bunch