# Extracting Public key from Private key using Botan

Tags: c++11, network-programming, botan

I'm trying to encrypt a message using asymmetric private-public keys.
In `Botan`, using `Load_key()` functions, I read the private key and want to extract it's public key from it. For constructing of an RSA public key in it's constructor, I'll need a "Algorithm Identifier" object and "key bits" which I have. The algorithm identifier object using `pcks8_algorithm_identifier()` function.

The problem is the "Key Bits" which returns a `secure_vector<unsigned char>` instead of a `vector<unsigned char>` and I encounter a `bad::alloc exception` when I want to pass it to RSA_PublicKey constructor.

Does anyone encounter such problem? If there is an alternative way of asymmetric encryption by loading keys from an input file in Botan I'll appreciate that

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: You can't extract the public key from the private key. The public key isn't in the private key.

Comment: @user207421 As you can see in the link [How to extract public key using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271197/how-to-extract-public-key-using-openssl) the public key is being extracted from the private key! By mentioning extracting doesn't mean it included the public key but to **earn the public key** maybe in other words !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Botan uses two interfaces to represent asymmetric key pairs: `Public_Key` and `Private_Key`. The `Private_Key` interface inherits from `Public_Key`. Therefore, when you obtained e.g. an `RSA_PrivateKey` via `PKCS8::load_key`, this object already represents both the public and the private key. That is, you can plug this object into other methods that expect a `Public_Key`.

For accessing the raw key bits, the `Public_Key` interface defines a `std::vector<uint8_t> public_key_bits()`. The `Private_Key` interface has an additional `secure_vector<uint8_t> private_key_bits()`. Therefore, every `Private_Key` instance should have both `public_key_bits`and `private_key_bits` available.

Reference: https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/pubkey/pk_keys.h

Additional note: The `secure_vector` class is a `std::vector` with a special allocator that ensures the underlying memory is overwritten when the object is destructed, so that sensitive information like private key bits are not remaining in memory. If you actually have to convert a `secure_vector` to a normal vector, the convenience function `Botan::unlock` is available (https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/base/secmem.h).