# Encrypt file using certificate resulting in 'Expecting PUBLIC KEY'

Tags: php, openssl

I've been given a certificate and told to encrypt a file using openssl.

1. This certificate is a .cer file, so I need to create a .pem file first. I have tried doing this using macOS's Keychain Access, and also using openssl in the terminal. They result in the same file, which starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.
2. I run the following command

   ```
   openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -inkey certificate.pem -pubin -in key.xml -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256 -out key.xml.enc
   ```
3. I get the error

> unable to load Public Key Error initializing context
>   4799456876:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start
>   line:pem_lib.c:697:Expecting: PUBLIC KEY

Am I using the wrong tools or the wrong approach? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143606/how-to-save-public-key-from-a-certificate-in-pem-format

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why yes it does, thank you so much!