# Using RSA with my private key by C#

Tags: c#, rsa, private-key

I'm provided a private key (a string). I have to generate a public key by that private key to encrypt data.
I don't know how to do. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: The public key should have been generated at the same time as the private key.  You should ask your private key provider.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244129/use-rsa-private-key-to-generate-public-key

Answer (score 1):

Simply by having the private key you can not generate a public key.
Private and public keys are generated in pair and should be provided to you for encrypting data.

However you still can sign data using private key alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var keypair = "Your keypair in xml format";
  using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
    rsa.FromXmlString(keypair);
    var publicKeyInXmlFormat = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
  }
```

Comment: How to insert keypair when I only have the private key as a string

Comment: You need something in this format: <RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>...</Modulus>
  <Exponent>...</Exponent>
  <P>...</P>
  <Q>...</Q>
  <DP>...</DP>
  <DQ>...</DQ>
  <InverseQ>...</InverseQ>
  <D>...</D>
</RSAKeyValue>