# Amazon Linux 2 User Creation with SSH Keys

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create some users with Amazon Linux 2 using adduser command but not able to create ssh files for login for those users.

If someone can help me out with the steps it would be really helpful

Comment: [Add New User Accounts with SSH Access to an Amazon EC2 Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)

Answer (score 1):

This is standard Linux. It is actually unrelated to the fact that you are using an Amazon EC2 instance.

In a typical organisation, **users should generate their own keypairs** and then provide the public half to the SysAdmins so they can put it in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. This way, even the SysAdmins don't have the private half of the keypair.

See: [How to use ssh-keygen to generate a new SSH key](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/)

Alternatively, users can generate a keypair in the Amazon EC2 console. The public keypair will be retained by AWS for launching future instances and the private keypair will be provided as a downloaded .pem file.

They can extract the public key from a private key with:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f key.pem > key.pub
```

See: [Use RSA private key to generate public key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246045/174777)